# Append only unique rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to read an external JSON API and write parsed values from it into google sheet. So each API call writes a new row into the sheet. The second requirement is to write the row only if it contains something else than already inserted rows - in other words append new row only if it is unique.

I've finished the first requirement. I've used `JSON.parse` and `appendRow` and it works with no problem.

Unfortunately, I cannot get thru the second requirement. I can not figure any construction nor find an example solution.

Does anybody have an advice how to append only unique rows from google apps script?

EDIT: My apologize for the above inexact post. Here are the details.

Below mentioned code is my solution for the first requirement:

```
function run() {

 var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://url/json-api").getContentText();
 var json = JSON.parse(data);

 var last = (json.last);
 var credit = parseInt(json.credit); 

 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("googleSheetID");
 var list = doc.getSheets()[0];


 list.appendRow([last, credit]);
}
```

So it simply append new row each time I run the script. Unfortunately, the returned JSON changes only from time to time. When I scheduled the script to run every 5 minutes it leads to many redundant rows.

However I don't want to run any kind of distinct after the redundant rows are written. I'd like to check if the new parsed data is unique and if so - write, otherwise nothing.

Comment: Show relevant code snippet.  Loop through all JSON  filter out unique values and `setValues()` instead of `appendRow`.

Comment: Is the JSON API returning 'row-like' responses? A nested map will require a different strategy?

Comment: @I'-'I I've edited the original post.

Comment: @Jonathon I've edited the original post

Comment: get last row value and check whether it's equal to `last`/`credit`, if so, quit, else appendRow

Comment: @I'-'I any idea how to code it? I'm beginner, I struggled with it and I would appreciate an example.

Comment: Did you write the above code? If so or even if you understand it, It shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @I'-'I Yes, I did. I mean I put togeher some examples and it works. However when it come to conditions, if-then-else construction etc. I am ending up quite confused.

Answer (score 1):

- getLastRow's value and check whether it's equal to `last`/`credit`. Then appendRow, if needed.
- Script Sample Snippet:

  ```
  var lastRow=list.getRange(1,list.getLastRow(),1,2).getValues(); //[[prev.last,prev.credit]]
  if(lastRow[0][0]!=last && lastRow[0][1]!=credit){
   list.appendRow([last, credit]);
  }
  ```